# Not able to set breakpoint in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and I am facing a weird issue from last few days. Whenever I try to set a break point, I get an error

```
"The Following breakpoint cannot be set", "The breakpoint failed to bind".
```

I don't know what settings have changed.

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio error dialog]

Comment: If everything else fails, maybe start a project from scratch, import all source files, and check if you have the same problem.

Comment: i check the same even i tried to open same project in other version of visual studio i.1. visual studio 2012 but its giving me same problem

Comment: Try to remove code until you have a smaller [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), post that here, so others may reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: Was this local debugging or remote debugging? I had this happen with remote, and I just had to republish, and make sure the latest pdb was in the bin folder with the publish.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Breakpoint Failed to Bind - Visual Studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732944/breakpoint-failed-to-bind-visual-studio-2015)

Answer (score 26):

I don't know if you resolved your issue but I faced the same problem and the "solution" was to change from "Release" configuration to "Debug".

Hope this Helps.

Cheers

Comment: Yes, this can move you forward, but this answer doesn't get at the root cause. It also doesn't help when your bug is in the Release version only.

Comment: I had the same problem and above resolved it for me, Thanks!

Comment: for some reason, my target was set to release and I did not notice it. thanks

Answer (score 7):

I used a MVC project and couldn't set any Breakpoints in the Razor-View.
All my projects were build in Debug-mode and a clean+rebuild didn't help either.
I had to remove this entry:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.AspNetHelper.VsInstrLocation" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\vsinstr.exe"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

in the `Web.config` and breakpoints worked again.

---

I found a related thread: [Visual Studio 2013/2015 profiler adds Not publishable lines in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523983/visual-studio-2013-2015-profiler-adds-not-publishable-lines-in-web-config)
Seems to be a Bug

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! 
However, I had another thing which silently interferred and that was Python tools for performance testing in VS. I had to additionally remove it too, so if anybody have this issue consider that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I've fixed it by creating a new solution file to the project files.

Comment: Might be worth deleting the .suo file first, to see if that helps?

Comment: Actually I haven't tried to delete the suo file, it looks like a better solution.

Comment: I have the same problem and deleting the .suo file didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check your program for subtle bugs. My failure chain that caused this error was:

1. I inadvertently put a duplicate key/value pair in App.config
2. Code that read that key/value via the ConfigurationManager silently failed
3. Structs returned by that code were invalid
4. Breakpoints on any line that referenced the invalid structs failed to bind

Once I fixed Item 1, everything started working again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Python code. Everything was ok, but

> "The breakpoint failed to bind"

If the **line number** (where is the breakpoint set) **is greater then *512***, than you can't debug. I simply reorganized my code, to be earlier that part with breakpoint and magically debugging is working again...

At this link you can find a full answer (at final rows):http://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/3007. 
So this is fixed in last version of Python Tools, but that version (2.2) works with VS2015 only.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was caused by a faulty merge of the `.csproj` contents, to be specific a `ItemGroup` contained a node which belonged in its own `ItemGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this myself.

To my surprise, I didn't observe I had a syntax error in a line further above.

With that one syntax error, it was causling the Studio 2019 IDE to fail in allowing me to set a break point anywhere.

So do double check if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

There could also be another open app that steals the "F9" shortcut.

Check your systray for open apps ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**
In VS2022 you can't set a BreakPoint on a variable declaration without an assignment.

**Solution:**
Set a BreakPoint on a variable declaration with an assignment or another line that is executable.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem, in my case it was because I had the wrong file extension on the file(s).  It was added to the project and was compiling correctly, but I was unable to set a breakpoint.

Don't know if anyone else will make the same silly mistake, but if they do...